# How can i use restclient-cpp in a Qt creator project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm working on my first QT project. I need to access a Rest API and decided to give https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp a try.

The issue is that i'm not able to make it work. I'm getting this error when building the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RestClient::get(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm not sure if this is correct. But i downloaded restclient-cpp and curl into 3rdparty/libs folder.

After that, added the following code in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/3rdparty/libs/"
INCLUDEPATH += "$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/3rdparty/libs/"
```

In main.cpp I added:

```
#include <restclient-cpp/include/restclient.h>
```

And the error happens when i add the following line to my code:

```
RestClient::response r = RestClient::get("http://localhost/customers");
```

Without this line, at least I can build the project.

What's the right way to do this?

### Additional information

Here is my folder structure:

```
bash-3.2$ cd 3rdparty/libs/
bash-3.2$ ls -lh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 42 fernando  staff   1,4K 24 Jan 23:30 curl
drwxr-xr-x  34 fernando  staff   1,1K 24 Jan 23:57 restclient-cpp
bash-3.2$ cd restclient-cpp/
bash-3.2$ ls
LICENSE                 README.md               config.guess            config.status           depcomp                 libtool                 stamp-h1
Makefile                aclocal.m4              config.h                config.sub              include                 ltmain.sh               test
Makefile.am             autom4te.cache          config.h.in             configure               install-sh              missing                 utils
Makefile.in             compile                 config.log              configure.ac            librestclient-cpp.la    source                  vendor
```

I compiled curl and restclient. Curl was compiled with a basic ./configure && make. Restclient was compiled with:

```
autoreconf -vif
./configure
make
```

Comment: First problem is that you are not linking to the library, you need to either write the .lib file name too (not only the path), or add an _-l LIBRARYNAME_ (without space) see the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Comment: Another solution can be to use QNetworkAccessManager class from Qt's network module, see the documentation: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, i'm using Mac OSX.

Comment: @Zlatomir I tried this: LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/3rdparty/libs" -lrestclient and some other variations but it didn't worked. It always results in "library not found for -lrestclient"

Comment: @Fernando 3rdparty is compiled or you got the source?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I updated my question with more information, including the folder structure.

Comment: @Fernando restclient-cpp is within the 3rdparty/libs? Are you trying to include the rest in another project as if it were a compiled LIB? If so, you would not have to build first restclient-cpp?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, restclient is in 3rdparty/libs/restclient-cpp. I already built it with the commands that are in my question. But I keep getting "library not found for -lrestclient".

Comment: I understand that you have compiled, but what was the return of the command to compile? Was he really executed properly, it may be that at compile time there was some failure of compatibility with MacOSX. Sometimes when I compile in like-unix step systems for some compatibility issue (variations in the GNU i also suffer).

Answer (score 1):

Install curl([example](http://decollector.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/how-to-use-libcurl-in-qt-on-ubuntu/)):

- install libcurl. open terminal and issue the command “sudo apt-get install  curl” without the qoutes.
- the do this in your terminal again:
- “sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev”
- “sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev”
- “sudo apt-get install libcurl4-nss-dev”

Insall restclient-cpp:

- ./autogen.sh
- ./configure
- make install

My .pro file example:

```
# Add restclient-cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lrestclient-cpp
```

And just add:

```
#include "restclient.h"
```